# Vimeo - allow users to to upload to my account

Tags: oauth-2.0, vimeo, vimeo-api

I want a few admin users on my site to be able to upload/edit videos straight to my own vimeo account without them having to authenticate each time with my credentials, I couldn't find much on this scenario on Vimeo, has anyone done anything similar?

I've noticed I have an OAuth access token from Vimeo, maybe I can use this somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a common misconception here, that authorization has anything to do with the user interacting with your application.

Authorization is simply how you want your app to interact with Vimeo.

If you want to interact on behalf of another user, you need their token. If you want to interact on your own behalf, you only ever need to use your own token.

So in the case you mention above, you simply need to hard code an access token into your app. This way all of your api calls will be made as if it's your own account. Users interacting with your app, such as uploading, will actually be using your account, and uploading videos to your account.

Comment: This guy knows what he's talking about.

Comment: Would having the access token on the client side allow the client to modify that accounts videos?  I want users to upload, but I don't want them having access to the full scope of privileges my Vimeo app is using... Is there a safe way?

Comment: Yes, if the client can view the access token (e.g. view source or monitoring network traffic via the browser dev tools) they can do anything that access token can.

You should create an access token that only has the upload permission and send that to the end user.